# Mean Vector of Weakly Stationary Time Series

Tags: time-series

$Y_t$ is weakly stationary and $Z_t$ is a sequence of IID normally distributed random variables with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\sum$.

For the bivariate AR(4) model $Y_t - \phi_4Y_{t-4} = \phi_0+ Z_t $, how can we show that the mean vector of $Y_t$ is $\mu = (I_2 - \phi_4)^{-1}\phi_0 $?

Answer (score 1):

Since the the process is weakly stationary then $E[Y_t] = E[Y_{t-4}] = \mu$.

Given that your model is $Y_t = \phi_0 + \phi_4 Y_{t-4} + Z_t$, since $Z_t$ has zero mean

$
E[Y_t] = E[\phi_0 + \phi_4 Y_{t-4} + Z_t] = \phi_0 + \phi_4 E[Y_{t-4}].
$

Then

$\begin{aligned}
E[Y_t] - \phi_4 E[Y_{t-4}] &= \phi_0\\
I_2 E[Y_t] - \phi_4 E[Y_{t-4}] &= \phi_0\\
(I_2 - \phi_4) \mu &= \phi_0
\end{aligned}$

Therefore, if $(I_2 - \phi_4)$ is invertible you get $\mu = (I_2 - \phi_4)^{-1}\phi_0$